Visualize JSON data on PBI Report
I would like to show some sample JSON data on Power BI report. This is just a documentation work. We get frequent request from consumers asking sample JSON structure and I can just redirect them to this report to make my work easier.
I tried to use textbox and published the report, but after publishing I can't select text and copy it. What other visual can I use to show the JSON where users can copy the text? or please suggest any other idea.


You could look at using HTML Content custom visual.

I have tried but I think it is similar to text box, just with additional formatting benefits. Please give me example if you have

Enable "Allow text select" in the Visual properties. https://i.sstatic.net/TMFUcCkJ.png

Not sure if I understood it very well but I recommend taking a look at JSON Crack and ToDiagram tools.

You could look at using the HTML Content custom visual.
It comes with an option to "Allow text select".

